# Identification of empty elements of a np.array

Tags: python, nan, numpy-ndarray

I want to do a for-loop over a np.array arr[r,c] with unpredicted NaN and want to identify those in order to impute them specifically according to the context.
Could anybody helP?

Comment: Please try to describe in us in more further detail and clarity, be more specific, and also don't forget to mention what you have tried so far. Please don't take in a negative way

Comment: assuming you have a numpy array `A` you can get a boolean map of all NaNs with `numpy.isnan(A)`

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to elaborate your question.

If your numpy array is 1D then do the following:

```
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    print(arr[i])
```

If your numpy array is 2D then do the following:

```
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        print(arr[i,j])
```

if you want to denote the 'NaN' values differently. Just use an if statement

```
if math.isnan(arr[i,j]):
    arr[i,j] = "anything"
```

Comment: `numpy.nan` does not equate the string NaN